# Excel numbers adding in one column top to bottom and continue next column from bottom to top

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there any formula for Excel numbers adding in one column top to bottom and continue next column from bottom to top and again next column continuation from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the columns and get the Total in one Formula
select an empty cell to have the sum in it, Click on AutoSum then select all the columns you need to sum and hit Enter unless you need the sum of each column alone, you can select all with one more blank row under and click AutoSum